# Criteria is not removed after I run this code in R

Tags: r, dataframe, row-removal

I am trying to remove `docked_bike` from the results table with the ff:

```r
library(dplyr)

a_v2 <- a_v1[!a_v1$rideable_type == "docked_bike" | a_v1$ride_length<0,]

a_v2 %>% group_by(member_casual) %>%
         summarise(number_of_rides = n(),
                   average_duration = mean(ride_length))

a_v2 %>% group_by(member_casual, rideable_type) %>%
         summarise(number_of_rides = n())
```

Output:

| member_casual | rideable_type | number of rides |
| --- | --- | --- |
| casual | classic_bike | 1132892 |
| casual | docked_bike | 5 |
| casual | electric_bike | 1162202 |
| member | classic_bike | 1922749 |
| member | electric bike | 1456488 |

What change on the code should I do so that I can remove the docked_bike?

Suggested Answer:

```
a_v2 <- a_v1 [a_v1$rideable_type != "docked_bike" & a_v1$ride_length<0,]
```

Updated Table:

| member_casual | rideable_type | number of rides |
| --- | --- | --- |
| casual | classic_bike | 24 |
| casual | electric_bike | 37 |
| member | classic_bike | 51 |
| member | electric bike | 32 |

From 1 million plus rides to double digits, I do not think that is the correct result.

Follow up question:

Is there a code to remove the `docked_bike` from the original table?

| member_casual | rideable_type | number of rides |
| --- | --- | --- |
| casual | classic_bike | 1132892 |
| casual | docked_bike | 5 |
| casual | electric_bike | 1162202 |
| member | classic_bike | 1922749 |
| member | electric bike | 1456488 |

Updated code and table:

```
a_v2 <- a_v1[a_v1$rideable_type != "docked_bike" | a_v1$ride_length<0,]
a_v2 %>% group_by(member_casual) %>%
     summarise(number_of_rides = n(), average_duration = 
     mean(ride_length))
a_v2 %>% group_by(member_casual, rideable_type) %>%
     summarise(number_of_rides = n()) %>%
     filter( rideable_type != "docked_bike")
```

| member_casual | rideable_type | number of rides |
| --- | --- | --- |
| casual | classic_bike | 1132892 |
| casual | electric_bike | 1162202 |
| member | classic_bike | 1922749 |
| member | electric bike | 1456488 |

Comment: Try: `filter(rideable_type != "docked_bike")`

Comment: The code worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following line:

```
a_v2 <- a_v1 [!a_v1$rideable_type == "docked_bike" | a_v1$ride_length<0,]
```

It is selecting rows where

1. `a_v1$rideable_type` IS NOT "docked_bike"

**OR**

2. `ride_length` < 0.

So if you have a "docked_bike" with a negative ride_length (<0) it will be selected.

Also, instead of `! <something> == <something>`, you can use `<something> != <something>`.

Comment: I am sorry I responded too soon. The line: a_v2 <- a_v1 [!a_v1$rideable_type == "docked_bike" | a_v1$ride_length<0,]  removed a lot of data. All the number of rides on my table became less than 100 which I do not think is right.

Is there a way to remove the docked_bike from the table row?

Comment: That depends on what do you exactly want to filter? Every row that is not docked_bike? What about the ride_length<0? Why did you added that part? @SamEspejo

Comment: Every row that is not docked_bike? Yes 
What about the ride_length<0? Because there are ride_length that has negative value

Answer (score 0):

following @RobertoT answer try to do:

```
a_v2 <- a_v1 [a_v1$rideable_type != "docked_bike" & a_v1$ride_length<0,]
```